# Powerflex Database File extensions

Tags: database, file-extension

I am trying to understand the different file extensions for the pfxplus powerflex database. Could someone please help telling me briefly what each file is for?

.k1
.k2
.k3
...
.k13
.k14
.k15
.fd
.def
.hdr
.prc
.pc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data files:

OK, so .dat is the data file.
.k1 -> .k15 are index files.

These are the critical data files for runtime.  (Combined with filelist.cfg or pffiles.tab similar to define what files are available overall).

.fd is the file definition, needed for compiling programs
.tag (which you did not mention) is needed only if you need to access field names at run time (such as using a generic report tool)
.def is the file definition in human readable form, and is not needed by any process but is produced so a programmer or user can understand the file structure.

---

Run time:

The .ptc files are the compiled threads interpreted by the powerflex runtime.

The .prc file is a resource file that is used at runtime in conjunction with the .ptc file - it defines how a character based program is to look in a gui environment in "g-mode".  It was the cheap way to upgrade character based programs when windows first started getting popular usage.

---

.hdr and .pc3 escape me at the moment, but are vaguely familiar - .hdr is probably another data file used with compression or special field types for later versions of pfxplus.  .pc3 may in fact be the .ptc files...

Comment: pr3 is the 32-bit Windows resource file. hdr is not Powerflex.